# After a successful DEVISE login, how to redirect user back to previous action that required login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, devise

I have an ajax voting button: If a user clicks on a "thumbs up" image, but is not logged in, then they should see a dialog box that asks them to login first.

To do this dialog box,I'm using jQuery and facebox bound to ajax:failure event.  Devise will raise a 401 Unauthorized if the user is not logged in.  facebox loads the remote html for the login in a pop-up dialog box that presents the DEVISE signin form.

Everything works except after successful login, user is redirected to the homepage.  It would be more intuitive if user was redirected back to the post they were looking at so they can continue their vote.

Is there a best practices way of achieving this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: How about an accept here?

Answer (score 19):

I do the following with Authlogic on Rails 3, perhaps you could use it or do something similar:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  after_filter :store_location
private
  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  def clear_stored_location
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end

  def redirect_back_or_to(alternate)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || alternate)
    clear_stored_location
  end
end
```

Then you can use something like `redirect_back_or_to dashboard_path` in your login action.

For some controllers/actions, I don't want to store the location (e.g. the login page). For those I just skip the filter:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  skip_after_filter :store_location
end
```

There's also a page in the Devise wiki on doing this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: This Devise wiki [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update) has a better, more bullet-proof solution, check it before you would use this code ;)

Comment: @ViktorBenei I wouldn't say it's objectively better or “more bullet-proof”, but it is stylistically different, despite operating very similarly.

Answer (score 4):

In ApplicationController write following:

```
after_filter :store_location
def store_location
  session[:previous_urls] ||= []
  # store unique urls only
  session[:previous_urls].prepend request.fullpath if session[:previous_urls].first != request.fullpath
  # For Rails < 3.2
  # session[:previous_urls].unshift request.fullpath if session[:previous_urls].first != request.fullpath 
  session[:previous_urls].pop if session[:previous_urls].count > 2
end
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:previous_urls].last || root_path
end
```

Source:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Comment: Note: The linked Devise wiki has a better, more bullet-proof solution, check it before you would use this code.

Comment: Wrong way for situation when go to /sign_out before. This path will be stored to previous_urls

Comment: I changed 'after_filter' to 'before_action' because my authenticate filter will redirect non-authorised request and therefore not calling :store_location otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

use a cookie.  Get the window.location.href that they are trying to go to and store it as a cookie.  On your home page, check for the presence of this cookier in the document ready function, redirect if its there

Comment: this is related to Rails redirects. Redirecting using Javascript is erroneous.