# Strange behaviour in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am currently working on a Rails project where I am encountering an extremely weird issue with Devise . Initially my client wanted me to have a two step registration i.e. a user fills out a basic information on website and than receive a confirmation link (Confirmable module). The confirmation link is going to take the user to the second step of registration where the user is going to fill out the rest of the important information needed to use the application. This was implemented successfully and was working great.

Recently my client decided to change this behaviour and just have one user registration page and no confirmation email being sent to user. I reverted all the Devise Controllers I modified to get the default behaviour and now there is an extremely weird behaviour in application. If I go to Sign up page and submit the form with user information it redirects back to the sign up page and also sign in the user. So the header changes to the one for signed in user but the page rendered is the registration page where as at the very basic level it should at least redirect the signed in user to the root path.

Same is the case with login page. The user gets signed in but keeps on getting redirected to the same login page. So far I have tried the following workarounds and none of them seems to work :

[Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)

[How To: Redirect to a specific page on successful sign in and sign out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out)

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989421/after-a-successful-devise-login-how-to-redirect-user-back-to-previous-action-th)

Also in addition to this I have not left even one single stackoverflow answer that resembles the problem I am having and also went through the issues in devise repo as well articles to see if I can find a clue to get this to work properly but none of them seems to resolve the issue.

I am working on this for almost two days now and none of the solutions are working out for me. Is there anyone else who also encountered this issue ? If so what was the solution to fix it.

Any help to resolve this issue would be very appreciated.

Note : I am also using Active Admin as well in this application which was implemented after I implemented the user registration flow. Is there anything I need to take care off on that side to resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: "I reverted all the Devise Controllers..." Did you remove :confirmable from the associated model?

Comment: @ethagnawl: Yes I did.

Comment: any chance we can see the code of your app? like in github or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reimplementing the devise gem with couple of custom configurations to get this working.